How to hide ecryptfs Private mount in Nautilus side panel?
I have a working standard-setup ecryptfs directories: ~/Private and ~/.Private. The ecryptfs mount shows on the Nautilus side panel along with the mounted drives. I want the mounted drives shown there, except the Private mount.
Is there a way to hide the Private mount from Nautilus?
Already checked these answers, but they don't seem to apply:

How do I hide / remove a partition from the Nautilus left panel?
How to hide bind mounts in nautilus?

(And the main reason I don't want Private being shown in Nautilus is less about somebody seeing it, than me accidentally clicking the unmount button.)


Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

I installed ecryptfs and set up the Private folder on a VM. I couldn't find a way to get rid of the Private shortcut in Nautilus. However, I couldn't unmount it either. It just showed a popup box saying it couldn't be unmounted.

Oh yeah. I finally tried that. It says it needs superuser privileges to do the unmount.  Well, I think I'll just keep the question in case someone needs this for a different purpose. Thanks for testing.
